# How to find index of minimum non zero element with numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 4x1 array that I want to search for the minimum non zero value and find its index. For example:

```
theta = array([0,1,2,3]).reshape(4,1)
```

It was suggested in a similar thread to use nonzero() or where(), but when I tried to use that in the way that was suggested, it creates a new array that doesn't have the same indices as the original:

```
np.argmin(theta[np.nonzero(theta)])
```

gives an index of zero, which clearly isn't right. I think this is because it creates a new array of non zero elements first. I am only interested in the first minimum value if there are duplicates.

Comment: Where's that other thread?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`np.nonzero(theta)` returns the index of the values that are non-zero. In your case, it returns,

`[1,2,3]`

Then,  theta[np.nonzero(theta)] returns the values

`[1,2,3]`

When you do `np.argmin(theta[np.nonzero(theta)])` on the previous output, it returns the index of the value `1` which is 0.

Hence, the correct approach would be:

`i,j = np.where( theta==np.min(theta[np.nonzero(theta)]))` where `i,j` are the indices of the minimum non zero element of the original numpy array

`theta[i,j]` or `theta[i]` gives the respective value at that index.

Comment: I don't understand what the i and j do here.

Comment: `theta.shape` returns `(4,1)` because of the reshaping you did. Hence, two indices are necessary

Comment: `i` and `j` being arrays is rather ugly, though, especially since Emily said she's only interested in the first minimum value if there are duplicates. Your code results in index arrays of all occurrences.

Comment: The question asks for the index of the minimum non-zero value. However, I have updated my answer with how to get the value as well.

Comment: If i try this answer on a bigger array, say an image array, then it returns an array of indices and not just a single index of the first value found minimum. Any solution how to do that?

Answer (score 6):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Solution utilizing numpy masking of zero value in array

import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
a = [0,1,2,3]
a = np.array(a)

print "your array: ",a

# the non-zero minimum value
minval = np.min(ma.masked_where(a==0, a)) 
print "non-zero minimum: ",minval

# the position/index of non-zero  minimum value in the array
minvalpos = np.argmin(ma.masked_where(a==0, a))  
print "index of non-zero minimum: ", minvalpos
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you @Emily were very close to the correct answer. You said:

> `np.argmin(theta[np.nonzero(theta)])` gives an index of zero, which clearly isn't right. I think this is because it creates a new array of non zero elements first.

The last sentence is correct => the first one is wrong since it is expected to give the index in the new array.

Let's now extract the correct index in the old (original) array:

```
nztheta_ind = np.nonzero(theta)
k = np.argmin(theta[nztheta_ind])
i = nztheta_ind[0][k]
j = nztheta_ind[1][k]
```

or:

```
[i[k] for i in nztheta_ind]
```

for arbitrary dimensionality of original array.

Answer (score 0):

## ndim Solution

```
i = np.unravel_index(np.where(theta!=0, theta, theta.max()+1).argmin(), theta.shape)
```

#### Explaination

1. Masking the zeros out creates `t0`.  There are other ways, see the perfplot.
2. Finding the minimum location, returns the flattened (1D) index.
3. `unravel_index` fixes this problem, and hasn't been suggested yet.

```
theta = np.triu(np.random.rand(4,4), 1)  # example array

t0 = np.where(theta!=0, theta, np.nan)   # 1
i0 = np.nanargmin(t0)                    # 2
i = np.unravel_index(i0, theta.shape)    # 3

print(theta, i, theta[i])                #
```

> [image: perfplot]
>  mask: `i = np.unravel_index(np.ma.masked_where(a==0, a).argmin(), a.shape)`
>  nan: `i = np.unravel_index(np.nanargmin(np.where(a!=0, a, np.nan)), a.shape)`
>  max: `i = np.unravel_index(np.where(a!=0, a, a.max()+1).argmin(), a.shape)`